# How to plot the spectrum of infinite dimensional operators?

Tags: plotting, physics, eigenvalues

For a finite dimensional operator it is easy to find eigenvalues in Mathematica. However, I found this example $H=p^2 + x^2 (ix)^\epsilon$ in this [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0303005.pdf). The spectrum of $H$ is plotted in figure 1 and looks like following:
[image]

How can one obtain this figure using Mathematica?

Comment: It is explained how to compute this spectrum in  C. M. Bender and S. Boettcher, Phys. Rev. Lett. 80, 5243 (1998). Just a side remark, you cannot simply write an operator and ask for a spectrum. There are always 2 ingredients needed: operator and boundary conditions (or domain). Thus, your question, as formulated, makes no sense.

Answer (score 5):

This restricts to a finite interval $[-r,r]$ and uses simple discretization with $2n+1$ points:

```
(* discretization parameters *)
r=10;
n=500;

(* matrix *)
p2=-n^2/r^2*SparseArray[{
      Band[{1,1}]->-2,Band[{2,1}]->1,Band[{1,2}]->1},{2*n+1,2*n+1}]//N;
x=Range[1,n]*r/n//N;
x2[eps_]:=With[{r=x^2*(I*x)^eps},
            DiagonalMatrix[Join[Conjugate[r]//Reverse,{0},r]//N]];

(* eigenvalues, please wait *)
ev[eps_?NumericQ]:=Map[{eps,#}&,Chop[Eigenvalues[p2+x2[eps],-10]]];
evs=Table[ev[eps],{eps,-0.7,2,0.05}];

(* plot *)
ListLinePlot[Transpose[evs,{2,1}],PlotMarkers->{"\[FilledDiamond]", 10},
             PlotRange->{{-0.7,2},{0,19}}]
```

[image]

Eigenvalues for $\epsilon = -0.5$ as an example:

```
ev[-0.5][[;;,2]]
(*
{13.5532 +4.00504 I,
 11.3696 -3.01092 I,
 11.3696 +3.01092 I,
 9.09025 +1.99448 I,
 9.09025 -1.99448 I,
 6.65531 +0.951423 I,
 6.65531 -0.951423 I,
 4.42176,
 3.19568,
 1.08691}
*)
```

Note that there seem to be three real eigenvalues, other eigenvalues are complex. The plot above only shows the three real ones.

Comment: why $n^2/r^2$ ?

Comment: See the [formula for the 2nd derivative as a limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative#Limit). The step size $h$ in that formula is $r/n$ in this case, therefore $1/h^2$ is $n^2/r^2$.